# If a method belongs to another class that extends Thread but is called from the main thread, will it be executed by main or a child thread? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I know there are some similar questions out there, but I couldn't find one specifically answering this question - apologies if I was wrong, and there is. Would the test.toString() method be executed by the main thread, or the test thread that I started prior to it being called? A group of us are arguing about this for test revision and I am curious to what the answer is.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       test = new ThreadTest("Test", 3);
       test.start();
       System.out.println(test.toString());
   }
}
public class ThreadTest extends Thread {
   public ThreadTest(String n, int x) {
       setName(n);
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return(getName() + ": x = " + x);
   }
   public void run() {
       //Nothing of any relevance to the problem occurs here
   }
}
```

Comment: I haven't added the run method as this is a simplified version of the code that we are discussing and it doesn't really do anything special - the toString() method isn't called in the run method at all.

Comment: A method of a class that extends Thread is no different from a method of a class that extends Date.  If you call using an object of the class then the method will be invoked.

Comment: Is there a way to tell by which thread specifically? Would it be main, or the test thread that runs before it is called?

Comment: Methods are called in the thread that calls them, even when it's a method on a Tread. toString() will be called in the same thread as main(). Also, don't go subclassing Thread. You're better off making Runnables.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to check :)

Comment: What David said -- a method runs in the thread where it's called.  Whether it's a method of Thread or BufferedInputStream makes no difference.

Comment: Maybe it would make more sense if you dropped the idea of methods running in threads.  Methods don't run.  Not in threads, not anywhere.  A method is just bytes in read-only memory.  It doesn't do calculations, just like how instructions printed on paper don't assemble your IKEA furniture.  _You_ assemble the furniture by _executing_ the instructions, and your program's _threads_ perform the calculations by _executing_ the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString()` call is executed on the main thread.  The main thread is invoking `Main.main()`; `main()` directly invokes `test.toString()`.

Just because your output prints the string "Test" doesn't mean that's the thread that is *executing* it.  `Thread` has state; `setName(...)` sets that state (and your class `TestThread` is a subclass of `Test` so it inherits this as well).  In your `toString()` implementation you're just printing that state... not the actual name of the executing thread.

To prove this, change your `TestThread.toString()` method to also print the name of the *currently executing thread* and re-run:

```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return(getName() + ": x = " + x + " executed on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }
```

You will see the following print to standard out:

`Test: x = 3 executed on thread main`

Full code:

```
public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest("Test", 3);
           test.start();
           System.out.println(test.toString());
       }    


}

public class ThreadTest extends Thread {
    private int x;
       public ThreadTest(String n, int x) {
           setName(n);
           this.x = x;

       }
       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return(getName() + ": x = " + x + " executed on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
       }
       public void run() {
           //Nothing of any relevance to the problem occurs here
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calls are always executed on the calling thread. Masses of code are based on this - for example the whole security and transaction infrastructure of the spring framework.

This fact can be proved rather easy:

```
public class Main {
    static ThreadLocal<String> threadContext = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        threadContext.set("Main");
        TestThread test = new TestThread();
        new Thread(test).start();
        System.out.println("Main: " + test.getContext());
    }

    static class TestThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            threadContext.set("ThreadTest");
            System.out.println("TestThread: " + getContext());
        }

        String getContext() {
            return threadContext.get();
        }
    }
}
```

And as @DavidEhrmann already said: You should implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.