# Java Method Call from Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have a game that has a thread for each client, maintaining information about that client, and a thread for the server that maintains information about the game world, would calling a method on the main server thread from one of the client threads run that method on the client thread, or the server thread?

Comment: The called method will always execute in the context of the caller. This means that method calls can never change the thread. This is why nobody calls the `Thread.run` method. You start it, the thread once started calls the method itself in it's context. Whether you name the place (class) that contains the method server thread or client thread is irrelevant

Comment: "calling a method on the main server thread from one of the client threads" - That doesn't exactly make sense, but it sounds like you might be asking something similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441751/if-a-method-belongs-to-another-class-that-extends-thread-but-is-called-from-the).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are like the literal meaning of the word a string of commands. A computer has a single [instruction pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) per thread to keep track where in the code the thread currently is. If you call a method, the program execution jumps there, and back once the method has finished. But it's not going to leave the thread. Code executing in a thread can never jump to a different thread.

The only way you can have your code execute in a different thread is to make the other thread call it for you.

But since you can't call the other thread directly, how can you make it call a method for you? Basically, program the other thread to wait for changes in a variable, and once it sees that variable change it can call the method.

So cross thread method invocation is actually communication through shared memory and it only works with special threads that are programmed to look at the shared memory. You can't execute code in Threads that just blindly do their thing.

To make it easy to program those things, we have `BlockingQueue`s in Java. Any thread can put things in and other threads can wait for something to come out. For example `Runnable`s that they execute.

```
    final BlockingQueue<Runnable> codeQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    Runnable code = codeQueue.take();
                    // call code in my context.
                    code.run();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            codeQueue.add(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Hello from Server Thread.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

In this example, `clientThread` causes `serverThread` to print "Hello from Server Thread." What `serverThread` does is also called an event loop. Because it waits for events and reacts to them.

Games typically have threads that do a (game) loop already. It's faily easy to add a line of code that checks for events and if it finds some to make it react to them. Anything bigger will already have a way to invoke code in different threads.

> would calling a method on the main server thread from one of the client threads run that method on the client thread, or the server thread?

In the client thread.